# PDO Issue With No Error Message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following snip of code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=DBNAME", $username, $password);
    echo "connected...<br/>\n";flush();
    $sql = "SELECT COLA, COLB FROM TABLEA LIMIT 10";
    echo "query:$sql--<br/>\n";flush();
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
    echo "statement:<pre>";print_r($stmt);echo "</pre>\nfetching...<br/>\n";flush();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result === true) {
        echo "result is true<br/>\n";flush();
    }
    else if ($result === false) {
        echo "result is false<br/>\n";flush();
    }
    else {
        echo "what?<br/>\n";flush();
    }
    foreach ($result as $key=>$val) {
        echo "key:$key - val:$val--<br/>\n";flush();
    }
    echo "done";
    $dbh = null;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die ($e->getMessage());
}
```

As you can see, I have a pile of debugging echo statements, yet the only ones I see are:

```
connected...
query:SELECT COLA, COLB FROM TABLEA LIMIT 10
```

I'm was expecting to see my statement object being displayed as well as my results, am I missing something?

Comment: Remove the try / catch and let us know the result.

Comment: Hey... you declare `$db` and then use `$dbh`?

Comment: @J. Bruni - I can't believe I missed that, thanks!  That solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

After you initialize the PDO object try setting the [error mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) higher.

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

The default is `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` which will output no warnings/errors. With this default setting, you have to poll [`errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to see error details.